# How to prevent selecting a choice in DAL dependent choice field

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

I am using **Django Autocomplete Light** in my application. In some of the views I have dependent choices with a parent - child relationship (eg. **Country** < **Cities**).

For chaining of choices I am using "**forward**" function as mandated in [DAL documentation](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html), as shown below.

```
    'country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete',
                                         attrs={'style': 'width:80px', 'data-placeholder': 'Click here to select...',
                                                'data-minimum-input-length': 2}),
    'city': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='city-autocomplete',
                                      forward=['country'],
                                      attrs={'style': 'width:40px', 'data-placeholder': 'Click here to select...',
                                             'data-minimum-input-length': 2}),
```

The page is working fine as expected with the caveat that, with no country choice picked up prior to city choices, the "city" choice field shows all available options (following are the images displaying the scenario).

**Scenario 1. Country choice not filled:**

[image]

In this instance, we can see all city choices with "**lo**" in their names are generated when **only the "city" choice field is used** (without first filling in the "**country**" choice field).

**Scenario 2. Country choice filled:**

[image]

In the second instance, when the city choice field is selected **after picking up the "country" choice** first, the names generated in the "city" choice field **are limited to the country** "United Kingdom".

**My question is:**

Is there a way I may prevent selection from the child field (field "**city**" here) without first having selected a choice from the parent field (here, the "**country**")? I am not averse to using **jQuery** in case there are no in-built options available in DAL.

Comment: post your autocomplete view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply using a filter in the **city** autocomplete **view**:

```
else:
    qs = qs.filter(country='')
```

and the job was done. Now the **city** choice field is not generating any choices if the **country** choice field is left blank.